# How to change status bar color of Angular app(Cordova - android)

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, statusbar

Status bar color should be same like current page background color. It should be dynamic.
I tried using cordova plugin but I'm not able to set different color for different pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely try to use [ngStyle] in your Angular for this depending on a condition you have, for example:

```
<div class="status-bar" [ngStyle]={'background-color': status === 'online' ? 'green' : 'red'}></div>
```

Comment: I want solution for mobile status bar not some css class color.